# Does the following Riemann integral exists?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

My question is: Does the Riemann integral

$$\int_{B_1(0)}|y|^{-a}\big|\frac{x}{|x|}-y\big|^{-b}dy$$ exists for all $x\in \mathbb R^2$?

$B_1(0)$ is the unit ball and $a,b<2$ such that $a+b>2$.

Well actually this is independent from $x$. But how one can show the existence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should it be $dy$ after the negative $b$ power?

Comment: yes,  i will edit it. Thanks :)

Comment: do you mean the improper Riemann integral?

Comment: @zhw. exactly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the integral does not depend on $x$, we can choose $x=(1,0)$. Write $y=r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Then $dy=rdrd\theta$, and your integral becomes:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta\int_0^{\infty}r^{-a+1}(1-2r\cos\theta+r^2)^{-b/2}\,dr$$
Near zero we are good because $1-a>-1$. When $r\to\infty$ the leading power of $r$ is $-a+1-b$, which is less than $-1$, because $a+b>2$. Consequently, the integral converges.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're dealing with an improper Riemann integral. Hint: Let $S$ be the sector $\{re^{it}: 0 < r < r_0, t_1< t < t_2\}.$ Then
$$\int_S |y|^p\,dy < \infty \iff  p>-2.$$

You can prove this by using polar coordinates.

Comment: In other words: The integral exists for the above assumptions?